# Не получается расшифровать

Tags: шифрование, decode

Имеется строка, такого вида **0B 00 FF 0C 05 A0 01 11 0B 06 CA FF 64**

Перепробовал много разных вариантов, не получается даже близко расшифровать данную строку. В какую сторону стоит посмотреть ?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что это в принципе возможно расшифровать?

Comment: @andreymal По этому, я и прошу здесь помощи. Можно или нельзя, если бы я знал

Comment: Мы тоже не знаем, этот набор буковок может значить абсолютно что угодно (или ничего не значить)

Comment: @andreymal ну, Вы не знаете. Возможно, найдутся люди. В любом случае, спасибо

Comment: Это текст или число? Что это должно обозначать в расшифрованном виде и на каком языке исходные данные?

Comment: @SpaceResearcher Текст. Есть "сервер", он передаёт по COM порту данные. Собственно, это одна строка из множества.

Comment: Ой, ну там что угодно может быть. Может он по 7 бит данные передаёт или шифрует как-то )  Одновременное наличие значений байта и сильно больших и сильно маленьких не похоже на просто текст в чистом виде.

Comment: Читать документацию к протоколу «сервера»

Comment: Зачем закрывать вопрос, на который уже дан вполне конкретный ответ, реально помогший задавшему вопрос? Понятно, что часть голосов за закрытие была отдана в момент, когда ответа ещё не было, но когда ответ уже есть и хороший, зачем голосовать за закрытие??

Comment: @CrazyElf потому что в вопросе как не было деталей, так и нет. Закрывают не ответ, а вопрос. Если автор ответа как-то догадался о чем вопрос - это еще не значит, что не вопрос не нуждается в исправлении.

Comment: @Dmitry Дополните, пожалуйста, свой вопрос тем, что вы писали в комментариях к вопросу и к ответу - текст, картинки, любая информация. Чтобы вопрос стал лучше качеством и его больше не закрывали.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если постоянно 0B 00 FF это стартовая последовательность. По 00 FF калибруется частота, скорость передачи на устройстве без кварца.

0C похоже на длинну сообщения за исключением контрольной суммы 64 в конце.

Посередине данные. Код команды и параметры.

Первое что нужно - модель, тип, назначение устройства, методички, документацию, гарантийки - собрать как можно больше бумажек. Собрать бумажки того же производителя на другие устройства, собрать бумажки на такое же устройство другого производителя.

Чтоб разобрать это нужно точно записать что делает устройство и контроллер в момент посылки. Какие кнопки нажимаются, в какую сторону барабан крутится. Всё по секундам.

Записать как можно больше данных на каждую операцию.

Одну команду я разбирал с 30 однотипных строк например.

По одной строчке это не разобрать)

А ещё возможно там Манчестер.

Comment: События прилетают в таком виде: 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K56ar.jpg

Comment: @Dmitry ну по этой картинке можно сказать что второй байт это номер посылки.

Comment: А может и нет. Там ещё один счётчик на убывание.

Comment: Вообще, суть такая. Есть сервер, с приёмником ( антенна ). Ловит сигналы. Она же подключена к ПК. На ПК свой софт, который получает события эти, обрабатывает и заносит в БД изменения. Чайник вскипел, отдал команду, антенна поймала, обработала, занесла в БД изменения. Вот это всё - результат мониторинга COM порта.

Comment: Так записывайте - чайник включился - отметку, вскипел-отметил, кнопку нажал - байтики поменялись.

Comment: Антенна точно с мозгами? Сфоткай внутренности. Если без мозгов, то начни с манчестера.

Comment: Вот вся связка. Именно такая у меня. https://imgur.com/v6kbW83

Comment: Похоже с мозгами) тогда просто тыкай кнопки и смотри что меняется

Comment: Получилось расшифровать)